# Complex Search and return function in VBAExcel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and struggling to find a solution for this and cannot find an answer on here.

I have a large database that continues to grow daily. The database consists of 2 sheets. Sheet 1 is to capture data and spans from Column A to column BF. Sheet 2 is merely a collection point filled with formulas to collect data from sheet 1. I did not create this workbook/database and it is not very well designed in my opinion, but it is what I have to work with; and changing it is not really an option.

What I need to do: 
I need to create a 3rd Sheet (already created the sheet) that produces the following complex search...

I need 1 cell to be an entry point where a name is entered. I need to search the database for every instance of that name in columns AO to AX from the first entry (which is on row 17) to the last entry (keeping in mind there are 20 to 40 new entries per day so it must be able to grow). That's the easy part.

I need to receive from my search 4 things.

1. The total number of times the name appears in the search area (Columns AO to AX).
2. The total number of times the name appears in 4 of the columns and the total it appears in the other 4 separately (4 columns are "Pass" in 4 categories and 4 of them are "fail" in the same 4 categories).
3. The total number of times the name appears in each of the 8 columns
    *I was able to do this using countifs*
4. (This is what I cannot do). I need to grab information from 3 completely different columns in each row that the name occurs.

For example: If the name appears in column AO and AQ but on different rows (which it most likely will) 
I need to grab the information from Columns A,B,and C for the row in which the name appears and copy & paste that information onto sheet 3 underneath the 'count' information.

I am able to accomplish 1, 2, and 3 by using a countifs function which is hidden on sheet 1. The result of the function is carried over to sheet 3 by using an =Sheet1!(cell reference). I hope I typed that right. The countifs function references a cell in sheet 3. I.E. =COUNTIFS(Sheet1!AU17:AU2500, Sheet3!A1). this allows me to count if column AU has any instances of whatever I type into A1 on sheet 3. By creating 8 columns with this formula and then transferring the results to sheet 3 I can capture the initial data.

Now of course the big boss wants the information found in columns A, B, and C for whatever rows those names appear in. Since "Charlie" may appear in any of 8 columns and any of what is currently more than 2000 rows, and may appear a number of times, it is clear that VBA is my best solution, but being new to VBA I am struggling to find the right combination of codes and variables.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: @Ralph. Thank you for the comment. I thought I had done a pretty good job on my question. I don't actually have any code written on this issue because I just started learning VBA yesterday and am lost. I have learned the basics of how to select cells and change worksheets etc...but this is still quite beyond me. I will keep pressing on and hope to get some code written that does something, but I understand you are not here to just write code for folks. My apologies if my question suggested that was my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started: here is a generic findall function you can use to find all the cells in the search range:

```
Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

Once you have the range found you can loop through each row in the range (e.g. For Each rw in Rng.Rows) and extract the data from columns A,B and C to the destination sheet.

****** EDIT ******

So I thought I would throw together the code as it is a bit of a challenge to extract this data. I think the following should work for you...

As it stands, enter the search term in 'A1' of sheet 3 and it will populate columns B:D with the data from row 2 onwards in the same sheet.

```
Sub ExtractData()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet3")

    Dim LastRow As Long, RowCounter As Long
    Dim SearchRange As Range, FoundRange As Range, rw As Range
    Dim Val As String: Val = wsDest.Range("A1")

    With wsSrc
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Set SearchRange = .Range("AO17", .Cells(LastRow, "AX")) 'AO-AX
        Set FoundRange = FindAll(Val, SearchRange)
    End With

    'Clear Destination Sheet (except header row)
    With wsDest
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Intersect(wsDest.UsedRange, wsDest.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    ' Copy Data
    RowCounter = 2
    Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, FoundRange.EntireRow.Rows) 'Expand Range to entire rows of Range
    For Each rw In FoundRange.Rows
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 2) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 1)
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 3) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 2)
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 4) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 3)
        RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
    Next rw

End Sub

Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to wrap my head around what you wrote. I understand some of it, but I'm struggling to keep up with the code. for the function, do I just pick one of those, or is that set up so I can run all of those as optional? If so, when I try to change the _ I just get an error. How do I set the parameter for the "search box"? I'm sorry for all the confusion, I am as new as new can get at VBA.

Comment: OK, so for the function; it's essentially very like the Range.Find function that comes in-built with VBA (google: Excel VBA find function). Other than 'What' everything else is optional, so you don't necessarily need to use them. The underscore character in code signifies that code continues on the next line (it's a line break) so removing them will break the function (however you could remove them all and have the function call all on one line; we add the underscore in for readability)

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I will keep working on this and hopefully have some code to show everyone and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do that. I am going through the code now to understand what, and why it is doing what it is doing. I am incredibly grateful as you have solved my primary problem. I hope to learn to be able to do this on my own. I am trying to add something to the criteria, but I think I'm either inputting it wrong, or in the wrong place.

Comment: Since these response boxes are so short, here is what I have   With wsSrc
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Set SearchRange = .Range("AO17", .Cells(LastRow, "AX")) 'AO-AX
        Set FoundRange = FindAll(Val, SearchRange)
            If SearchRange = .Range("AT17", .Cells(LastRow, "AX")) Then
            SearchRange.Font.Color = rgbRed
            End If                                                                          I am trying to get the results from col AT-AX to change the text Red.

Comment: So I added the "if" parameter after the "set Foundrange" but I get a run time error 13 with a type mismatch. Any thoughts? And how do I respond with code like you did so I can show it properly? Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Hi, This follow on will be a separate question. Can I suggest you accept this answer then as it solves the question above, then post a second question; you can therefore add the updated code and state what you are trying to alter and the issues you have; it will get fresh views and further people can then work on it...

Comment: You can always ask a number of further questions; so If you keep what you want to achieve as a smaller work package then you will be more likely to get solutions posted